# Why is this integral defined?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

In the exercises of the calculus textbook I'm reading, I am asked to evaluate this definite integral $\int_1^\sqrt 2 \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}$. The problem here is that the book states that if a function is not bounded on a closed interval then it is not Riemann-integrable on that closed interval, and the function above certainly is not, however, the solution to the integral is equal to $\frac π4$ and it is obtained using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Now my question is if that integral is defined then why is the integral $\int_1^\sqrt 2 \frac{dx}{x-1}$ said to be divergent even though the functions appear to have the same properties.

Comment: This is an [improper integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral). A limit has to be taken in order to give it a finite value.

Comment: Indeed this is not "properly Riemann integrable" however $\int_a^{\sqrt{2}} \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}$ exists in the proper Riemann sense for all $1<a<\sqrt{2}$, and the limit of these as $a \to 1^+$ is what we mean by the improper Riemann integral. In the Lebesgue theory the situation is a bit less subtle. With $\int_1^{\sqrt{2}} \frac{1}{x-1} dx$ you can again look at $\int_a^{\sqrt{2}} \frac{1}{x-1} dx$ where $1<a<\sqrt{2}$ and they all exist, but the limit as $a \to 1^+$ is $+\infty$.

Comment: I suspect you're reading your textbook wrong when you quote it as saying "if a function is not bounded on a closed interval then it is not Riemann-integrable on that closed interval". A true theorem is "if a function is bounded on a closed interval then it is Riemann-integrable on that closed interval", but you've quoted the converse (or inverse) which is not an equivalent statement.

Comment: @GregMartin Actually, "a function defined on a closed interval being unbounded implies it is not Riemann integrable" form is true while "a function defined on a closed interval being bounded implies it is Riemann integrable" is false.

Comment: I forgot to state the continuity assumption, it's true. But the OP's improper integral and many other examples show that being unbounded is not an impediment to being Riemann integrable. Unless one's semantics differentiate between "Riemann integrable" and "integrable" for improper integrals.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, first of all the book has not introduced improper integrals yet, so basically whenever I see a definite integral with an integrand that is unbounded on the interval of integration should I assume that it refers to an improper integral?

Comment: @SamuelVasquez Yes. Unbounded functions have no (proper) Riemann integral, so it is meaningless to "solve" them using the fundamental theorem of calculus without further justification. This is likely an oversight by the book author. If this is something that your professor has written then you should probably notify them of this. I doubt they meant introducing this example without first discussing improper integrals explicitly.